# Vue3 Problem on Generating UI Using Data Value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have following scenario in Vuejs version 3:

```
    <div id="test">
        <input type="number" v-model="dim">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span v-for="i in parseInt(dim)">
            <span v-for="j in parseInt(dim)+1">
                <input type="text">
            </span>
            <br>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.2/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script>
        const Test = {
            delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
            data() {
                return {
                    dim: '3',
                }
            }
        }
        Vue.createApp(Test).mount('#test')
    </script>
```

What I want here is to generate `dim x dim+1` input box based on value of `dim` in UI. But when I increase the value of `dim` from input box where `v-model="dim"` is binded then it gives me following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: create a computed property of dim and use that in your template other than the v-model and the first v-for

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-troubleshooting-v-model?file=index.html). Can you fork it to reproduce the problem?